# django unittest import error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, importerror

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\mech10>cd superlists

C:\Users\mech10\superlists>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: lists.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: lists.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mech10\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 428,in    _find_test_path
module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
File "C:\Users\mech10\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name__import__(name)
File "C:\Users\mech10\superlists\lists\tests.py", line 9
self.assertEqual(found.func,home_page)
                                     ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

tests.py

```
    from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
    from django.test import TestCase
    from lists.views import home_page

    class HomePageTest(TestCase):
      def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):
        found = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(found.func,home_page)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^$', 'lists.views.home_page', name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_page():
  pass
```

I followed the instructions from a django test book but I don't understand why my test script doesn't work.

Comment: it says that in your `tests.py` file you have both tabs  *and* spaces used for indentation, when you should have either one or the other.

Comment: @iulian I dont think the problem is that. Because, even if I say like the following code from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
'from django.test import TestCase'
'from lists.views import home_page'
'class HomePageTest(TestCase):'
  'def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):'
    'found = resolve('/')'
 'self.assertEqual(found.func,home_page)' nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. I started to use backspace for all the lines and clear all the irrelevant spaces in tests.py and the problem is solved now.